# GROK Pattern error in the separate patterns file

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have defined my pattern in the patterns file and reading them from my logstash module as the below block

```
grok {
      patterns_dir => "../patterns/cisco-ftd"
      match => [ "message", "%{CISCOFW302013_302014_302015_302016}",
                 "message", "%{CISCOFW302020_302021}",
                 "message", "%{CISCOFTD607001}"
                  ]
      tag_on_failure => [ "_grokparsefailure" ]
    }
```

While the first two patterns get recognized, the third one `CISCOFTD607001` doesn't get recognized and the output log gives the below error.

```
exception=>#<Grok::PatternError: pattern %{CISCOFTD607001} not defined>
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my parser but sure.
[Here is the message and the corresponding parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kISS.png)

Here is my pattern `%FTD-%{POSINT:[event][severity]}-%{POSINT:[syslog][id]}: %{DATA}:%{IP:[source][ip]}/%{NUMBER:[source][port]} to %{DATA}:%{IP:[destination][ip]} %{GREEDYDATA}`

Comment: Update your question with the content of the file `../patterns/cisco-ftd`, also, put all the relevante information to your problem in your question, do not link to external sites when it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question.

It worked well when I changed `patterns_dir => "../patterns/cisco-ftd"` to absolute path.